Movie about a killing cult
I don't remember much as I saw it in Tv like 10 years ago. 
It's a horror/thriller movie. Don't recall any actors. The main characters are investigating a group of people that are in a killing spree. They seem like a cult since they dress like (but in black):

They seem supernatural because they are fast, strong and nothing seems to stop them but at the end of the movie you discover that they took a german drug that gives you like adrenaline so you are stronger and maybe fast healing the wounds ...
Thats all I remember. 

Reminds me of "Crimson Rivers II: Angels of the Apocalypse" from 2004.

As with the first movie, the pair's investigations intertwine and soon they are looking at a giant conspiracy involving a secretive group of monks on amphetamines led by Heinrich von Garten, played by Christopher Lee, searching for a treasure hidden by King Lothair II somewhere near the Maginot Line.

Here is an image of one of the monks:

Here is the trailer:



